# What is the best way to store message threads?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, application-design

I'm integrating a messaging feature into an application written in `Javascript` and would like to know which is the preferred data structure of storing messages.

The two structures I can think of so far are these:

```js
const thread = [
  {
    id: 1,
    user: 'joanne',
    message: 'Hello, How are you?',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    user: 'jack',
    message: 'I\'m good thanks, and you?',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user: 'joanne',
    message: 'I\'m also good thanks, and you?'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    user: 'jack',
    message: 'I\'m good thanks, and you?',
  },
];
```

or

```js
const thread = {
  1: {
    user: 'joanne',
    message: 'Hello, How are you?',
  },
  2: {
    user: 'jack',
    message: 'I\'m good thanks, and you?',
  },
  3: {
    user: 'joanne',
    message: 'I\'m also good thanks, and you?',
  },
  4: {
    user: 'jack',
    message: 'I\'m good thanks, and you?',
  },
};
```

Are there any benefits of one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form is a list, the second is an index.

A list is the simplest possible structure to store messages.
It's natural too, because usually the ordering of messages matters.
When a new message arrives, simply append to the end.
A common use case of messages is printing them,
or only a slice of the list, for example the last `N` messages,
possibly with some filters applied.
Such operations are straightforward to implement as simple iteration.

An index implies a specialization for some purpose.
If you want to find messages by id,
the second structure is useful.
If you never need to find messages by id,
the index is completely useless.
Iterating over an index in chronological order is generally not optimal,
as indexes are not designed for that.
It's not obvious how you would display the last `N` messages of the index.

Conclusion:

- Use a list as the base
- If you need to find messages by id, and only then, use an index too, in addition to the list

Comment: I agree.  It also tends to be structured more like you'd expect a database to be structured, which isn't an advantage in of itself, but should you ever need to abandon this approach with a more robust database approach, you'll be thanking yourself for picking an easily adaptable solution.